# Dynamically add and remove input elements with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a table:

```
<div>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p id='1' className="foo"> Boom </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id='2' className="foo"> Bang </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id='3' className="foobar"> Pew Pew </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
</div>
```

I want the data inside it to be editable in-place. Thus I want to substitute `<p>` element with an `<input>` and then substitute it with `<p>` again, but with new value. I've been doing it with jQuery and now made it with what seems to me as plain JS but with React. Code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'foo'){

      let element = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
      let element_value = element.innerText
      let parent_element = element.parentNode
      let new_element = document.createElement('input')

      parent_element.removeChild(element)
      parent_element.appendChild(new_element)
      new_element.setAttribute('class', 'input') 
      new_element.setAttribute('id', e.target.id)
      new_element.setAttribute('value', element_value)

    } else if (e.target.className === 'input') {
      
      let element = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
      let element_value = element.value
      let parent_element = element.parentNode
      let new_element = document.createElement('p')


      parent_element.removeChild(element)
      parent_element.appendChild(new_element)
      new_element.setAttribute('class', 'foo') 
      new_element.setAttribute('id', e.target.id)
      new_element.innerText = element_value
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('dblclick', this.handleClick)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('dblclick', this.handleClick)
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p id='1' className="foo"> Boom </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id='2' className="foo"> Bang </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id='3' className="foobar"> Pew Pew </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
    )  
  }
}

export default App
```

However this doesn't seem to me as a good practice. Could you give me hints on how to improve/change my approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to create a controlled component that handles all the logic for the editable cell, and store the values in the parent. I made a sandbox that you can [check out here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-tereshkova-r13sm?file=/src/App.js), but I'll add the code here as well.

That way the cell component provides all the view stuff needed, and the parent controls the logic and data for all the cells.

So, the editable cell handles the functionality of switching between views:

```
const EditableCell = ({ id, onEdit, className, value }) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  }, []);

  const onFinishedEditing = useCallback(() => {
    setIsEditing(false);
  }, []);

  const onKeyDown = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        onFinishedEditing();
      }
    },
    [onFinishedEditing]
  );

  return (
    <td>
      {isEditing ? (
        <input
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => onEdit(e.target.value, id)}
          onBlur={onFinishedEditing}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          autoFocus
        />
      ) : (
        <p {...{ id, className, onClick }}>{value}</p>
      )}
    </td>
  );
};
```

And then the app stores the cells' data and renders an `EditableCell` for each one:

```
export default function App() {
  // This stores the cells values and properties, you can
  // add or remove cells here are needed
  const [cellValues, setCellValues] = useState([
    { id: "1", class: "foo", value: "Boom" },
    { id: "2", class: "foo", value: "Bang" },
    { id: "3", class: "foobar", value: "Pew Pew" }
  ]);

  const onEdit = (value, id) => {
    setCellValues(
      cellValues.map((cellVal) =>
        cellVal.id === id ? { ...cellVal, value } : cellVal
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Click a cell to edit
      <tr>
        {cellValues.map((cellVal) => (
          <EditableCell
            id={cellVal.id}
            value={cellVal.value}
            className={cellVal.class}
            onEdit={onEdit}
          />
        ))}
      </tr>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This might not perfectly match with the functionality you're wanting, but should give you a starting point

Comment: Thanks, this will help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been promise to myself that i will made good deed at least one per day.I know that you write in class way but i stick to hooks so much that... sorry man :P

it call onChange when during editing you will press enter.

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Td = ({ children, editable = false, onChange, className, id }) => {
  const cell = useRef();
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    while (typeof children !== "string") {
      children = children.props.children;
    }
    return children;
  });
  const [oldValue, setOldValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!cell.current) return;
    const onEditMode = () => editable && setEdit(true);

    const target = cell.current;

    target.addEventListener("click", onEditMode);

    return () => {
      target.removeEventListener("click", onEditMode);
    };
  }, [cell, setEdit, editable]);

  const paragraph = useMemo(() => (
      <p id="1" className="foo">
        {value}
      </p>
    ),[value]);

  const input = useMemo(() => {
    const update = (value) => {
      setEdit(false);
      if (onChange && typeof onChange === "function") {
        onChange({
          id,
          newValue: value,
          oldValue: oldValue
        });
        setOldValue(value);
      }
    }

    return (
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={ e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={ e => e.key === "Enter" && update(value)}/>
      )
    },[value, setEdit, onChange, id, oldValue, setOldValue]);

  return (
    <td ref={cell} className={className}>
      {edit ? input : paragraph}
    </td>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  tableCellValueChange({ id, newValue, oldValue }) {
    console.log(
      `table cell id: ${id} value changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead></thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <Td 
                onChange={this.tableCellValueChange}
                id="special"
                editable>
                  <p>Bang </p>
              </Td>
              <Td onChange={this.tableCellValueChange} editable>
                <p>Bang</p>
              </Td>
              <Td editable={false} className="forbar">
                Pew Pew
              </Td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here you have [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dew-5ydob?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
[live example](https://5ydob.csb.app/)

Comment: thank you mate, hooks are interesting feature indeed.